# difference between tar zxf vs -xvf

Tags: linux, centos, zip, gzip, tar

I have a downloaded version of http://agentzh.org/misc/nginx/openresty-1.9.7.3.tar . I rename it to openresty-1.9.7.3.tar.gz.

I am trying to do the following in centOS-6.x:

```
tar zxf openresty-1.9.7.3.tar.gz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

whereas :

`tar -xvf openresty-1.9.7.3.tar.gz` works and untars to openresty-1.9.7.3.tar.gz.

Any reasons why the first one won't work? It works in my personal laptop but won't wont work in a server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`zxf` means: gunzip (the 'z' letter) and extract (the 'x' letter) from file (the 'f' letter, and the file name follows).
`xvf` means: extract (the 'x' letter) and be verbose (the 'v' letter) from file (the 'f' letter, and the file name follows).

You renamed the `openresty-1.9.7.3.tar` to `openresty-1.9.7.3.tar.gz`, but this didn't make it gzipped tar archive. So first command fails, because this can't be gunzipped.
Second command just verbosely extract the archive, without trying to gunzip it.